# CentOS 5.5 network problem

Tags: networking, centos, networkmanager

I have been made to install CentOS-5.5 on my desktop. The network is not working.
These following are the outputs of various commands.

```
#ifconfig
lo link encap:local loopback
inet addr 127.0.0.1 mask 255.0.0.0
.....(goes on)
```

There is no other device other than 'lo' in the ifconfig output.

```
#chkconfig --list|grep -i network
networkmanager 0:off .... (every thing off)
network (2,3,4,5 on ; and rest of them off)

#service NetworkManager status
networkmanager is stopped

#service network status
configured devices:
lo
currently active devices:
lo
```

there is nothing in the /etc/resolv.conf file

regards

Comment: What is the model of the network card?

Comment: @RenanBirckPinheiro output of `lspci |grep net` is `00:19.0 Ethernet controller: intel corporation unknown device 1502 (rev 04)` . I hope that adds some extra information

Comment: @RenanBirckPinheiro with a bit more searching it seems like this is  the CPU i am using is [link](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/optiplex-790/pd).  And the following is given in the connectivity section
Integrated Intel® 82579LM Ethernet LAN 10/100/1000     
Optional Broadcom® NetXtreme® 10/100/1000 PCIe card    
Optional Dell Wireless 1520 PCIe (MT, DT, SFF)    
Optional half-mini PCIe (USFF) WLAN card (802.11n)

Comment: can you try installing a newer version of CentOS (5.8 or 6.2)? It might be supported (instead of being recognized as an "unknown device") with an updated kernel.

Comment: @RenanBirckPinheiro centos-5.5 is the most preferred OS for us. I need to check if there are alternatives to make the network work before giving up!

Comment: You could try to install the CentOS 5.8 kernel package on CentOS 5.5.

Comment: You are using an old, unsupported version of CentOS with lots of security bugs? Why on earth don`t you update?

Comment: Intel has very good drivers that blend into your OS. Download them, compile them and install them.

Comment: I have the same issue with my VM machine CentOS 5.8 As you said, your network card, **"00:19.0 Ethernet controller: intel corporation unknown device 1502 (rev 04)"** Actually this message indicates it's not supported by your OS. So i suggest you to reconfigure your network adapter with other than intel chipset, in your virtual environment check for other adapter type and replace your intel adapter type.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, your network card is

`00:19.0 Ethernet controller: intel corporation unknown device 1502 (rev 04)`

This makes me think that, being seen as an 'unknown device', it's not supported by CentOS 5.5. Can you try a more recent CentOS version (CentOS 5.7 or CentOS 6.2)?

According to [this](http://raghukumarc.blogspot.com/2011/11/ethernet-controller-not-detected-with.html), CentOS 5.7 should recognize the card.

Try installing kernel-2.6.18-274.18.1.el5.x86_64.rpm and kmod-igb-rhel5u7-3.0.6_k2_1.1-1.el5_7.x86_64.rpm from [a mirror, such as this one](http://linux.mirrors.es.net/centos/5.7/updates/x86_64/RPMS/).

(replace x86_64 with i386 if you're using 32-bit CentOS).

The kmod-igb package is for supporting the network card you have in that machine.

Comment: CentOS-5.5 is the most preferred OS for us. I am not sure but, does installing driver for that particular network card solve the problem? I am ready to take a beating before giving up!

Comment: You can try to install the CentOS 5.8 kernel (get the RPMs from a mirror).

Comment: CentOS-5.7 is last one in the CentOS-5 series. I shall install it's kernel and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Indeed, my fault, I thought the latest CentOS was 5.8.

Comment: I have installed the rpm file I found in [this](http://vault.centos.org/5.7/os/SRPMS/) directory. (if you search "kernel" in that page, you could easily find it.) The new kernels that show up at boot time are 2.6.18-**194.el15** and  2.6.18-**194.el15PAE**. (neither of them work) But actually kernel I have installed is of version 2.6.18-**294**. Also, that rpm file was an SRPM, it if matters..

Comment: You don't want the SRPM files (they're for building from source). 

Will add more to my answer since this might be quite large for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

`ifconfig -a` will give you the status of *all* interfaces. If you do not specify any arguments or options, ifconfig will only display *active* interfaces.

If you have a desktop GUI environment you may be able to [follow this guide](http://fedoramobile.org/Members/MrHappy/system-config-network) to get networking up. If you do not have a GUI desktop environment installed, then `system-config-network-tui` as root may be of use. If you do not have the package providing the tui executable, you may have to install from the Internet or CDROM. I realize the paradoxical nature of what I just said, and you may be able to temporarily enable the NIC by running `ifup eth0` and `dhclient eth0`, if you expect a DHCP address. Even if this succeeds, this should **not** persist between reboots unless you make further configuration changes and save them.

Specifically, if you edit /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 you should be able to set the device to be brought up on boot (ONBOOT=yes) and use DHCP (BOOTPROTO=dhcp). Again this depends on whether or not you expect DHCP.

Comment: there are no entries in any of the tabs in the system-config-network window..